# Ruby Compass Compiler not working, error on line [54]

Tags: ruby, rubygems, compass

Ruby Compass not working, code is bellow, and I've tried 10-20 methods on the web, any suggestions ?

In the screenshot you'll find an easier way to read the terminal dump of my gems and the error, in case you want to take something from there, you'll find the text under the screenshot

Thanks,
Cheers,
Robert

[image]

```
    RubyGems is a sophisticated package manager for Ruby.  This is a
basic help message containing pointers to more information.

  Usage:
    gem -h/--help
    gem -v/--version
    gem command [arguments...] [options...]

  Examples:
    gem install rake
    gem list --local
    gem build package.gemspec
    gem help install

  Further help:
    gem help commands            list all 'gem' commands
    gem help examples            show some examples of usage
    gem help gem_dependencies    gem dependencies file guide
    gem help platforms           gem platforms guide
    gem help <COMMAND>           show help on COMMAND
                                   (e.g. 'gem help install')
    gem server                   present a web page at
                                 http://localhost:8808/
                                 with info about installed gems
  Further information:
    http://guides.rubygems.org
sh-3.2# gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.5, 1.2.0)
CFPropertyList (2.2.8, 2.2.0)
chunky_png (1.3.1)
compass (1.0.1)
compass-core (1.1.0.alpha.0, 1.0.1)
compass-import-once (1.0.5)
ffi (1.9.3)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.8.1, 1.7.7)
libxml-ruby (2.7.0, 2.6.0)
mini_portile (0.6.0)
minitest (5.4.1, 4.3.2)
multi_json (1.10.1)
nokogiri (1.6.3.1, 1.5.6)
power_assert (0.1.3)
psych (2.0.5, 2.0.0)
rake (10.3.2, 0.9.6)
rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
rb-inotify (0.9.5)
rdoc (4.1.1, 4.0.0)
rubygems-update (2.4.1)
sass (3.4.2)
sqlite3 (1.3.9, 1.3.7)
test-unit (3.0.1, 2.0.0.0)
sh-3.2# compass compile -e production --force
LoadError on line ["54"] of /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb: cannot load such file -- rgbapng
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

Answer (score 9):

Fixed by installing the following compass extensions :

```
gem install compass-normalize
gem install compass-rgbapng
gem install toolkit
```

Comment: Just wanted to note for others, I'm having the same issue as you on a fresh install of Yosemite and this did not fix it for me.

Comment: I had a Gemfile, so in my case, I needed to run `bundle install`.

Answer (score 1):

That did not fix it for me. However, I was able to fix it by reinstalling the compass gem using

```
gem uninstall compass
gem install compass
```

I think you can probably fix it even easier by just updating the compass gem to the latest version using `gem update compass`.

Note: If you use rails, you might also have to update your `compass-rails` gem. Otherwise, the `compass watch` command will start to hang. See this [issue on github](https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails/issues/185)